# Should I use regex for registration/login forms?

Tags: php, regex, authentication

Is it enough to use mysql_real_escape_string and strip_tags for username/password inputs or should I also include regex? The website uses deprecated MYSQL.

For example:

```
if (!preg_match( "/^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{0,3}$/",$_POST['email'])) {
    $error = "Invalid email or password";
```

Comment: It will be better if you use the Regex in JavaScript to verify the email before the validation.

Comment: @BadroNiaimi which wouldn't be enough, because a POST request with malicious code could be sent anyway!

Comment: For passwords, only escaping is needed from security point of view since it's not displayed anywhere. For emails you should use regex, ready validator, or PHP `filter_var` (with `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` flag) function. For usernames, it depends on your policy. Do you accept any characters in usernames or just letters and digits or something else.

Comment: @dragoste Thanks, that's what I needed.

Comment: _“Is it enough to use mysql_real_escape_string and strip_tags for username/password inputs”_ – no, it is too much already. strip_tags has no business being involved here at all. If I _want_ my password to be `foo<bar>baz`, then there is no reason whatsoever why you should intervene and either say that’s not allowed, or even worse, use a manipulated version of my password without even telling me. If you have _aesthetic_ reasons for allowing only certain characters in user names, fair enough – but those should be enforced via a whitelist, and not by applying strip_tags.

Comment: @CBroe won't mysql_real_escape_string do the same if you use special chars in your password?

Comment: @SaulTigh: The same as what? As strip_tags? No, of course not, they both do completely different things.

Comment: Validation and escaping are two different things.

Comment: You may also find these resources helpful - autoregex.xyz and regexr.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always better to validate email(inputs) before pass data to MySQL, fortunately, you don't have to use `regex` for email validation, PHP have built-in function [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) for validation. Which is much faster than regex validation.

Syntax will be:

```
if(! filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    //Email not valid, 
    $error = "Invalid email or password";
}
```

Comment: You may also find these resources helpful - https://www.autoregex.xyz/ and https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 1):

With RegEx you can verify the format of the username/password.
The regex you are using is not reliable, for example it doesn't match email@blablabla.info or any new TLD longer than 3 chars.

For e-mails I use this one:

```
/^[[:alnum:]|\.|\-|_]+@[[:alnum:]|\.|\-|_]+[A-Z]+$/i
```

Please note that for passwords you must write a different check based on the characters you want to allow.

Comment: can you please explain this alnum and other characters in your regular expression?

Comment: `[:alnum:]` will match all alphanumeric values (numbers and letters).
Then I added some punctuation chars, such as `.`, `-` and `_`.
`[a-z]` will only match alphabetic chars.
`/i` at the end means case-insensitive.
As you can see up there, there is a better way to check for valid emails in php.